# How to make a right sidebar for a wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How I can make a right sidebar for a wordpress theme and integrate with advanced search like the concept below:
[image: right sidebar concept]

sidebar.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * The sidebar containing the main widget area.
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package custom
 */

if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
    return;
}
?>

<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</div><!-- #secondary -->
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) ) : ?>

     <div id="tertiary" class="widget-area" role="supplementary">
      <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ); ?>
     </div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

style.css for sidebar

```
#secondary { /* left Sidebar */
width: 18rem;
margin-left: -67rem;
float: left;
position: relative;
}

#tertiary { /* right Sidebar */
width: 18rem;
margin-right: -23rem;
float: right;
position: relative;
}
```

How I can achieve it in an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the WordPress Codex for information about customizing the sidebar. This page has a lot of information on it about the sidebar: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Your_Sidebar

If you are asking how to get a menu to expand from the side of the screen, there are many different CSS/JavaScript implementations, but perhaps something like this jQuery Slick Plugin might help: http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-slick-plugin/examples/

If you are asking how to create the custom search functionality, then that is going to be very dependant on the plugins you are using and what you are searching for. This article does give a good overview of getting started with customised search capabilities and custom search forms in WordPress: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/build-your-own-custom-wordpress-search/

Comment: I already looked for multiple times and its not answer what I want

Comment: I'm not even sure if you are asking about getting a menu to expand from the edge of the screen or if you're asking about the PHP side of things, but I'll add something to the answer. The question is not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your `sidebar.php` set up in your template file where you want it; it could be `index.php`,`single.php`,`page.php` or whatever

I see two ways of doing it

1 - Install some fancy search plugin and add it your sidebar using **Dashboard - Appearance - Widgets area**

2 - In your **Widget area** you can add **Html content** where you will have your search form OR hardcode it in your `sidebar.php` OR create `search-form.php`(where you will have your form) and include it in your `sibedar.php` or directly to the template file using `get_template_part()`

here are some useful links:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Comment: Could you give an example about some fancy search plugin?

Comment: I did not use any search plugin before. Try something from this list - https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=search